# SMTP c++ client

Tags: java, c++, smtp

I need to connect to a `pop3` server and get the list of all mails located in there. Is there some convinient library I could use in `c++`. In Java, we usually use [commons-net](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net) in order to operate on such `SMTP` connections. I'm looking for something similar. The issue is wouldn't like to write all of the boilerplate code to create `SMTP`-connection via low-level sockets.

Comment: POP3 and SMTP are two completely independent protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Google for libESMTP - it's the onlycolor library I know of that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Found this if you haven't found something already.
Open source for C++

http://www.vmime.org/